# Qt class disconnected from its .ui file?

Tags: qt, class, user-interface

Somehow my `MainWindow` in my qt project has become unlinked from the `.ui` I created in qt designer (I am using qt creator as my IDE). The implementation file does have both:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
```

But if I add a widget (for example, a `lineEdit`) into the UI in the designer, if I try to do anything with that widget in my implementation I get an error (and of course, the autocomplete does not detect that widget).

Can anyone assist? Please let me know if this is not descriptive enough. Thanks!

[**EDIT**]
This seems to be a problem with my moving from qt 4.6 to qt 4.7. In Qt4.6, the header files generated for the UI were put in the same directory as the project. In Qt4.7, it places them in the build directory. So I had updated header files, but my program was linking to the wrong one. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to link to the right header files now. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't used Qt Designer, but maybe it would help to `uic` the changed UI file?  (Might be doable via an IDE menu option, or with the command-line `qmake` tool, or with a manual `uic` command.)

Comment: Well the header file does exist (and does seem to be updated if I change something and do a general build), and my other interfaces are fine too. I'll give this a shot, though.

Comment: check your .pro file for the `UI_DIR` entry... do you have one?, if yes, what is its setting?

Comment: I do not have a UI_DIR entry.

Comment: Can you show us your .pro file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a default qmake based project, when you create a new file you have the option of choosing whether or not it is added to the project.  You choose this in the form of an "Add to Project" checkbox on the "Project Management" dialog.

To make sure the form is managed by QtCreator, edit your project's `.pro` file so that it sees the `.ui` file by adding an entry to `FORMS`.  For example, if you have one form, `mainwindow.ui`, and a second `newdialog.ui` that needs to be added, you could change it using any of the options below:

Option 1:

```
FORMS += mainwindow.ui \
    newdialog.ui
```

Option 2:

```
FORMS += mainwindow.ui newdialog.ui
```

Option 3:

```
FORMS += mainwindow.ui
FORMS += newdialog.ui
```

The first option is used by QtCreator 1.3.1.

As long as the `ui` files are registered in FORMS, the makefiles generated by qmake should be sufficient for the current version be it Qt-4.6 or Qt-4.7.

Comment: I already had my Forms += mainwindow.ui etc.ui. The problem was that it was linking to the wrong generated ui_x.h and adding the UI_DIR = ../src/ seems to have fixed it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: The point I tried to make near the end of my post was that if you were to regenerate your makefiles from your .pro file, everything should work correctly without the need to specify a UI_DIR or any other options. The generated makefiles are specific to the version of qmake (and their corresponding qt version) that generated them.